# Problemas com violação de protocolo no FTP Server (FTPWebrequest)

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, ftp

Na empresa que trabalho tenho dois servidores: um local que pertence a nós e um provedor de terceiros. Tenho que fazer uma cópia dos arquivos do sistema que está no provedor de terceiros para nosso servidor local. Basicamente um *backup*.

Estou utilizando a classe `FTPWebRequest` para fazer os métodos de listar, download e criar diretório caso não existam.

Enquanto eu rodava aplicação no meu PC, conseguia baixar normalmente. Quando mando a aplicação para nosso servidor local e ponho para executar acontece o seguinte erro:

```
"The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation."
```

no seguinte método:

```
WebUI.FTPClient.MakeDirFTP(String diretorio)
```

O método que ele alega dar o erro é esse:

```
 public void MakeDirFTP(string diretorio) {
     try {
         FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://diretorio/subDiretorio/Backup/" + diretorio);
         request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
         request.Proxy = null;
         request.UseBinary = true;
         request.UsePassive = true;
         request.Timeout = 6000000;
         request.KeepAlive = true;
         request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
         FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         responseStream.Close();
         response.Close();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         throw ex;
     }

}
```

Essa aplicação roda no mesmo lugar que irá receber o *backup*. Já procurei em todo lugar e não achei uma resposta.

Comment: Olá Pedro. Você poderia editar a questão com o *stack trace* completo? Outra coisa, do seu servidor remoto você consegue acessar o ftp com o usuário e senha da aplicação e executar essas operações (e.g., `mkdir`)?

Comment: Oi Anthony, consegui aqui, obg :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera descobri qual era o erro :P

A aplicação já estava dentro do servidor então não havia motivos para tentar autenticar o login, já que a aplicação já tinha acesso aos diretórios.

Fiz isso para criar os diretórios dentro do servidor FTP.

```
if (ConfiguracaoLocalOuServidor.EstouNoServidor())
            {
                string caminho = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("").Replace("\\Admin", "") + "\\Backup\\" + diretorio + "\\";                                      
                Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho);
            }
```

Obrigado pela atenção :D